# Regex used in Express JS Middleware doesn't pass url parameters

Tags: regex, express

I'm using the following regex in a piece of middleware located in [this](https://github.com/TheMasteredPanda/TMP-Notes/blob/develop/backend/app/routes/notebook.ts#L67) file:

```
/\/notebook\/\w+\/(?!delete|save|entry)\w+/
```

The regex, as far as i've tested, works as intended (the demonstration below is copied from the console):

```
 /\/notebook\/\w+\/(?!delete|save|entry)\w+/.test("/notebook/5e5f8bcf0f3ec87973a7e2a5/5e5f8bcf0f3ec87973a7e2a6?id=5e5f8bcf0f3ec87973a7e2a4")
true
```

However the parameters of the endpoint do not get passed into the middleware:

```
   console.log app/routes/notebook.ts:71
   Params: {} Original URL: /notebook/5e5f8f85562da17d3088ddaa/5e5f8f85562da17d3088ddab?id=5e5f8f85562da17d3088dda9

● Notebook entry can be accessed

Failed: Object {
  "detail": "Regex matched path for /notebook/:notebookId/:entryId, but the entry id undefined cannot be found",
  "status": 500,
  "title": "Serverside error",
  "type": "generic-001",
}

  319 | 
  320 |                 if (res.status !== 200) {
> 321 |                   fail(res.body);
      |                   ^
  322 |                 }
  323 | 
  324 |                 expect(res.status).toBe(200);
```

[Line 321](https://github.com/TheMasteredPanda/TMP-Notes/blob/develop/backend/tests/endpoints/notebook.test.ts#L321)

I assume this is because express is not associating the [requested endpoint](https://github.com/TheMasteredPanda/TMP-Notes/blob/develop/backend/tests/endpoints/notebook.test.ts#L313) with the middleware, however I am unsure as to how is isn't associating as the middleware is executed upon the request, and I can get all other variables in the, such as the id in the query section of the url and the originalUrl, just not the parameters of the url.

How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Express extracts the params object from url based on the `:` notation. So, if your regex don't actually have the notation it will not extract that patterns and serve them as objects. It finds the middlewere, but it won't parse the object.

Try something like `/\/notebook\/:notebookid\/:entryid?\w+\/(?!delete|save|entry)\w+/`.

Also, I think your code can get a little confused on the URLs that don't use the entryid, like `/notebook/:notebookId` (line 163).